# Almost periodic functions in weak mixing extension

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, approximation-theory

In Theorem 3.4.6 of the '[Lecture notes on ergodic theory](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/peters10/teaching/Spring2011/ErgodicTheoryNotes.pdf)' by Jesse Peterson, it is shown that in a weak mixing extension, every almost periodic function is trivial. I have a doubt in the proof of this implication. First, let me recall the definition of weak mixing extension and almost periodicity from the note.

(Note that by the notation $\sigma_{\gamma}(f)$ we mean the action of the group element $\gamma\in \Gamma$ on the function $f$.)

**Definition 3.4.2:** Let $\Gamma$ be a countable group. An extension $\Gamma\curvearrowright (X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ of a probability measure preserving action $\Gamma\curvearrowright (X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a weak mixing extension if for any $\epsilon >0$ and any finite set $F\subseteq L^2(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ such that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{A}}(f)=0$ for all $f\in F$, there exists $\gamma\in\Gamma$ such that for all $f,g\in F$ we have $\|\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{A}}(\sigma_{\gamma}(f)\bar{g})\|_1<\epsilon$.

**Definition 3.4.3:** Let $\Gamma$ be a countable group and let $\Gamma\curvearrowright (X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be an extension of a probability measure preserving action $\Gamma\curvearrowright (X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$. A function $f\in L^2(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ is almost periodic relative to $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ if for all $\epsilon >0$ there exist $g_1,... ,g_n\in L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ such that for all $\gamma\in\Gamma$ we have $\sigma_{\gamma}(f)\in_{\epsilon}L^2(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)g_1+\cdots+L^2(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)g_n$.

Now, to show the above mentioned implication, the author picks an almost periodic function $f\in L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ (relative to $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$) such that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{A}}(f)=0$. Then for a given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $g_1,...,g_n\in L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ such that for every $\gamma\in\Gamma$, there are $k_1^{\gamma},...,k_n^{\gamma}\in L^2(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ such that $\|\sigma_\gamma (f)-\sum_{j=1}^nk_j^{\gamma}g_j\|_2<\epsilon$. Then the author argues that since $\sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\|\sigma_{\gamma}(f)\|_{\infty}=\|f\|_{\infty}$, so we may assume that $K = \sup_{1\leq j\leq n,\,\gamma\in \Gamma}\|k_j^{\gamma}\|_{\infty}<\infty$.

The argument in the last line above was not clear to me, i.e.

**Question:** How can we assume that $K = \sup_{1\leq j\leq n,\,\gamma\in \Gamma}\|k_j^{\gamma}\|_{\infty}<\infty$?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\sigma_{\gamma}$? that's not a standard notation...

Comment: Again I am not sure about Jesse's notes (why don't you read the classical paper by Furstenberg? it is well worth the time for any dynamics person). Anyhow, you may take $g_{i}$ orthogonal to each other, and using the fact that $L^{2}$ distance dominates $L^{1}$ (finite measure space), the WM property (+orthogonality) would show that the inner product there (well its projection over the $A$ sub-sigma algebra) is equal (or smaller) than sum of the $L^{2}$ norms of $k_{j}^{\gamma}$ (and notice their sum equal to the $L^{2}$ norm of $f$, up to maybe epsilon)...

Comment: , so the $L^{2}$ norm of $f$ is less than epsilon, for any positive epsilon..

Comment: $\sigma_{\gamma}$ stands for the action of the group element $\gamma\in \Gamma$ on the function space. I want to get an uniform $L^\infty$ bound of the collection $\{k_j^{\gamma}\}_{1\leq j\leq n,\,\gamma\in \Gamma}$. But I did not get how are you arguing that, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I didn't say his argument is correct, I just gave an alternative argument showing that the $L^{2}$ norm of $f$ is arbitrarily small. Again, probably the original paper of Furstenberg or the book of Glasner carry all the details (and more...). Studying from incomplete and unpolished lecture notes posted online always carry some risk...